# Azure function : Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.FunctionMetadataLoader: At least one binding must be declared

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

Getting below error after publishing function to azure.
[image: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.FunctionMetadataLoader: At least one binding must be declared.]

I have no clue what is missing here. Function is .net 5 based.

This function is calling graph api to get user details.
[image: function code]

I have added function.json file as below :

[image: function.json]

Comment: Please provide us with some (relevant) code, information about the hosting, what you tried and didn't work. In it's current form, this question is no fit for Stack Overflow. Please refer to [ask].

Comment: See if you are missing  `[Function("name")]                                                         public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req,
          Iloggger log)`  or are missing type:token in binding like [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/using-microsoft-graph-in-an-azure-function/ba-p/317434).Can you please provide the document link you are following.

Comment: You should not be adding the function.json file. Are you getting an error when you are running it locally ? Is it an in-proc app or isolated function app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. Problem was when I publish code to Azure, 'RUN FROM PACKAGE' key was getting added to app settings.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone finds this page when looking by the error description - you will get this error if you declare an activity function without any parameters.

```
[Function("MyActivity"]
public void MyActivity() {}
```

You must have a parameter, decorated with `[ActivityTrigger]`, even if you don't use it.

```
[Function("MyActivity"]
public void MyActivity([ActivityTrigger] object _) {}
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. saved me a few hours of madness :-D

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below is the cause.

The error says atleast one binding is required.
You must have probably missed adding the package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage  in your function app.According to the steps in [install-binding-extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs-code?tabs=csharp#install-binding-extensions) something like below:

[image]

Because according to the azure functions [best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices?tabs=csharp#configure-storage-correctly)

> functions requires a storage account be associated with your function
> app. The storage account connection is used by the Functions host for
> operations such as managing triggers and logging function executions.

If it is done don’t miss to add [package reference](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage) after adding the extension from nuget package to your function project.

If this is not the case , you may provide more configuration details regarding the same for further investigation.